# Execute method on persisted assembly from dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

It is possible to call a method that resides on a "Normal" assembly from a dynamically constructed assembly?

For example, assembly B is dynamically constructed(via Emit) from assembly A and assembly B needs to call a static method that is defined on assembly A.

```
public interface IMapper
{
  void Map();
}

public void CreateDynamic() {
  AppDomain app = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
  AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName("assemblyB");
  AssemblyBuilder assembly = app
    .DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
  ModuleBuilder module = assembly
    .DefineDynamicModule(assembly.GetName().Name, "b.dll");

  TypeBuilder type = module.DefineType("MyType",
    TypeAttributes.Public |
      TypeAttributes.Class |
      TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
      TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, null, new[] {typeof (IMapper)});

  MethodBuilder method = type
    .DefineMethod("Map",
      MethodAttributes.Public |
        MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
        MethodAttributes.Virtual);

  ILGenerator il = method.GetILGenerator();

  Func<int, TimeSpan> func = i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);

  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 10);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, func.Method);
  il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

  Type t = type.CreateType();

  IMapper mapper = (IMapper) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
  mapper.Map();
}
```

When the Map method is executed a MissingMethodExcetion is thrown and I do not now the reason for that.

Comment: Provide a code sample and/or check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908156/call-static-method-with-reflection

Answer (score 1):

Below line causes a `private static` method to be created in the class at compile time.

```
Func<int, TimeSpan> func = i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
```

So what you are trying to do becomes something like this.

```
public class TestClass {
    private static TimeSpan CompilerGeneratedMethod(int i) {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
    }

    public void CreateDynamic() {
        // Other codes...

        var methodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("CompilerGeneratedMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 10);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodInfo);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Other codes...
    }
}
```

Now we just created a class in AssemblyB that is trying to call a `private static` method in another assembly. If it was directly written in C# it may look something like this.

```
public class MyType : IMapper {
    public void Map() {
        TestClass.CompilerGeneratedMethod(10);
    }
}
```

Since the `CompilerGeneratedMethod` is `private` it cannot be accessed. So rather than using a lamda, let's try using a real declared `public` method.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static TimeSpan HandWrittenMethod(int i) {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
    }

    public void CreateDynamic() {
        // Other codes...

        var methodInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("HandWrittenMethod");

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 10);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodInfo);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Other codes...
    }
}
```

Now we have one minor problem. We are trying to call a static method using `Callvirt` which should be used for late-bound methods. Instead of `Callvirt` we should be using just `Call`.

```
 il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo);
```

Comment: I cannot create a real public method, since the mapper is intended to be used by external libraries, so the name of the method is not know upfront.