# CAKE: Unsafely load assembly

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.21.1.0.

I want to add a task that performs the equivalent of this PowerShell operation:

```
$dlls = @(${dll1}, ${dll2})
$dlls | % { [Reflection.Assembly]::UnsafeLoadFrom($_) }
[StaticClassFromLocalLibrary]::SomeStaticMethod(SomeArgument)
```

I have decided not to use [the CAKE PowerShell add-in](https://github.com/SharpeRAD/Cake.Powershell) because running the PowerShell script directly throws the error `<script>.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system`. Because of my employer's IT policy, I am not permitted to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to circumvent the problem. This is why I want to translate the steps taken in the PowerShell script directly into instructions in CAKE.

Initially, I wrote these lines in my CAKE script:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(dll1);
System.Reflection.Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(dll2);
StaticClassFromLocalLibrary.SomeStaticMethod(SomeArgument);
```

However, an exception was thrown, saying that the name `StaticClassFromLocalLibrary` was not found in the current context.

I then added this line to my CAKE script:

```
#r @"\\hostName\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Some.Local.Project.dll"
```

However, because it was not loaded in an unsafe manner, another exception was thrown, this time informing me that the DLL could not be loaded.

How can I use the `#r` directive (or any other CAKE command) to specify that I would like the DLL to be loaded in an unsafe manner?

**EDIT:**

I have solved my problem by consulting [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908156/call-static-method-with-reflection) and adopting the suggestion in the accepted answer.

Comment: Possibly you could add an app config to sort it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no build in unsafe loading in Cake but as it's just C# what you can do is just convert your PowerShell snippet into C#

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom("./tools/Addins/Newtonsoft.Json/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll");

var type = assembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert");

var method = type.GetMethod("SerializeObject", new [] {typeof(object) });

var SerializeObject = (Func<object, string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                                           typeof(Func<object, string>), null, method);

var json = SerializeObject(new { Hello = "World"});

Information("{0}", json);
```

Which will output something like

```
{"Hello":"World"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have already fixed my issue by consulting this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908156/call-static-method-with-reflection

Comment: Ok, but does the above answer your question? In general good idea if you find the answer yourself to go back to the question and answer and accept your own answer so people know it's been sorted. Better practice than editing the question hours after someone has posted an suggested answer. That way you value the time of people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, devlead -- I shall do as you suggest.