# How to execute static methods by name

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, static

I have an XML file with classes name like this:

```
<ActiveMonitorsList>
        <MonitorName>CertificatesMonitor</MonitorName>
        <MonitorName>ServicesMonitor</MonitorName>
        <MonitorName>LogsMonitor</MonitorName>
        <MonitorName>DBMonitor</MonitorName>
</ActiveMonitorsList>
```

Each of this classes containts a method: `bool SingleCheck()`;

I would like to execute this `bool SingleCheck()` method for each class that is in this XML file.

What is the best way to do this?

This is what I have so far - it doesn't work:

```
foreach (string monitorName in monitorsList)
{
    Type thisType = GetType();
    MethodInfo singleMonitorMethod = thisType.GetMethod("{monitorName}.SingleCheck");
    bool methodResult = singleMonitorMethod.Invoke(...);
}
```

- In place of (...) - don't know what to put here, but I want to get
  the result of the method (it's always bool).
- All of those methods I want to pass as paramters are static.
- I guess delegates, Actions or Func<> have to go in here...

Thank You very much in advance!

Edit: Each name in XML points to a separate class. Each class have the same named method: `public static bool SingleCheck()`.
What I want to do is:

- get all the monitors names (classes names will be the same)
- invoke a method (it has the same name in each class) inside EVERY
  class present on that list.

**EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED:**

When I first created my project, I included separate folder for all monitors. Then I changed my mind, deleted this folder and added manually SAME FILES to my solution. In this way - those files still had "`using <namespace>.Monitors`"...
And that's why I couldn't list those classes and the Types were still nulls...

Thanks for all suggestions ! ;)

Comment: where do you execute the foreach loop? what `Type` do you expect from the call of `GetType()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call static method with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908156/call-static-method-with-reflection)

Comment: @Selvin It's not really a duplicate as here it's not just about invoking a MethodInfo for a static method, but also about to find the method within a type.

Comment: I am looking for a CLASS name, the XML hold CLASSES names. Inside each of those public classes there is a method called SingleCheck(). This method is static.

Comment: Edited the question, it's quite complex so I am not sure if this is understoodable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to take this overload of the method [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke?view=netframework-1.1) It wants an object(calling instance) and a set of input parameters for the method from you.

Since it is a static method, you can calmly pass `null` as the first parameter and because you method does not have any parameters you again can calmly pass `null` as the second value. Don't forget to cast `object` to the corresponding return type. In your case `bool`.

```
bool methodResult = (bool)singleMonitorMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

To get the correct Type you actually need to know the namespace! So this would look like this:

```
foreach (string monitorName in monitorsList)
{
    string typeName = $"{yourNameSpace}.{monitorName}";
    Type thisType = Type.GetType(typeName);
    MethodInfo singleMonitorMethod = thisType.GetMethod("SingleCheck");
    bool methodResult = (bool)singleMonitorMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

If the loop is in the same namespace this should also work:

```
Type thisType = Type.GetType($"{GetType().Namespace}.{monitorName}");
```

Comment: I have seperate public classes and in each of them there is the same method called "SingleCheck". I cannot use my namespace name directly.

Comment: @KamilTurowski " I cannot use my namespace name directly" are the classes in different namespaces?

Comment: Well, they are all in the same namespace. Though - You suggested {yourNameSpace}.SingleCheck -> it doesn't return a class name - the one that I need.

Comment: @KamilTurowski damn'it that is a big copy paste typo. Sorry for that I changed it I meant : `string typeName = $"{yourNameSpace}.CertificatesMonitor";`

Comment: Actually: string typeName = '$"{yourNameSpace}.{monitorName}' inside of the foreach loop.

Comment: @KamilTurowski there is still my first question unanswered. Where is this loop situated? in a different class? same namespace as the names from XML?

Comment: Loop is inside of RoutineCheck() method, which is in timer in Main() method (it's console app), but it's still the same namespace ;) But yes, it's in different class then the every "monitor" method...

Comment: @KamilTurowski happy to hear mate. If it is in the same namespace then you can get it by this call: `GetType().Namespace`

Answer (score 1):

`thisType.GetMethod("{monitorName}.SingleCheck")` won't work because of two reasons. 1) You forgot the string interpolation $-sign and thus are searching for a method called "{monitorName}.SingleCheck" which obviously can't exist with such a name. 2) Instead of `thisType` you need to provide the type containing the method.

[Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke) needs to be called with the instance as first parameter - null for static methods - and an object array for the method parameters.

Assuming that your monitor classes are in the same assembly like your current type you would need to do the following:

```
foreach (string monitorName in monitorsList)
{
  Type monitorType = GetType().Assembly.GetExportedTypes().Single(x => x.Name == monitorName);
  MethodInfo singleMonitorMethod = monitorType.GetMethod("SingleCheck");
  bool methodResult = (bool)singleMonitorMethod.Invoke(null, Array.Empty<object>());
}
```

I prefer [Array.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty) over `new object[0]` or `new object[] { }` because it doesn't create a new object every time.

**Edited:** Changed the type discovery according to Mong Zhu's comment that `GetType(monitorName)` does need the fully-qualified name.

Comment: Loop is inside of RoutineCheck() which is in timer, but it's still the same namespace ;)

Comment: @MongZhu You are correct. I changed the type discovery piece.