# Assembly class invoking error while calling exe in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to access an exe which is in different folder and invoke a method through this using assembly with the following code. This part of the code is in one project

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\abc\\def\\Test\\test_1\\bin\\Debug\\TestEngine.exe");
        Type type2 = assembly.GetType("Test.Program");
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type2);
        MethodInfo[] methods = type2.GetMethods();
        object[] staticParameters = new object[1];
        staticParameters[0] = "";
        object result = methods.Where(a => a.Name == "Implementation").First().Invoke(instance, staticParameters);
```

Please note : i can access the method through the where condition but it is not invoking the method
and the method i want to access is having code. And this part of the code is in different project folder

```
 public static void Implementation(string input)

        {
           some code here
        }
```

BUT it is giving me error

'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
inner exeception : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

please note : I need to load through assembly only and process.start din't work for me.

Comment: type2.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).  And don't create an instance to call a static method, pass null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908156/call-static-method-with-reflection/11908192#11908192

Comment: @HansPassant do i have to change the aruments in the second code or its fine ?

Comment: sorry it says the same error if i remove the arguments from the second method and i keep the same method with argument it says mismatch count... kindly help me with working code